# Python requests.timeout not working in Virtual Box VM

Tags: python-requests, electron, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an electron app that automatically runs a Django (Python) server. This server contains REST APIs that the frontend of the electron app calls.

The behavior of the APIs is that they are acting as "bridges" between the frontend and an online API. Basically, the flow is:
Frontend calls the Django server -> Django server calls an Online API, **via requests library in Python** -> Online API returns a response to the Django server -> Django server returns a response back to the Frontend.

The requests call made by the Django server to the Online API has a timeout of 20 seconds. The expected behavior is that if the Django server is calling an Online API and the internet is cut off, the Django server will timeout after 20 seconds and will return back a response to the Frontend.

This (i.e. the timeout) is already working if the electron app is ran outside a VM but inside the VM, it's not ending in 20 seconds.

What might be the problem?

Comment: It can be a lot of things. However we need some code to be able to determine more

Comment: @ManosKounelakis which part of the code of the whole electron app do you need? And what might be examples of these "lot of things"?

Comment: It might be some wrong configuration on the python code some misconfiguration on the electron app or even some network configuration.  But we need at least something to examine . Yeah put your code in a github repo perhaps